# Get value from THIS element that shares class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

So the app I'm making is pulling data from a json file and rendering  the data dynamically. I'm using classes because I don't think I should pull an ID name from the json file to be added into the html element.. (or should I?) - How do I get querySelector to get the value from the one I click on? And not from every element that has the same class?

```
 <button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button> 
 <button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>

var selectedSong = document.querySelector('.playBtn').value;
```

json to Button Value to onClick send value to be a new Variable

Answer (score 0):

```js
var play = document.getElementsByClassName('playBtn');

for(var i=0, len=play.length; i<len; i++){
    (function(index){
        play[i].onclick = function(){
            alert(play[index].value);    
        }
    })(i);
}
```

```html
<button class="playBtn" value="one">button one</button>
<button class="playBtn" value="two">button two</button>
<button class="playBtn" value="three">button three</button>
<button class="playBtn" value="four">button four</button>
<button class="playBtn" value="five">button five</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understands you properly...

Something like this should help

Here you just listen for clicks on all `playBtn`, but gets value from the one you click.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var button;

  button = event.target;

  if (button.classList.contains('playBtn')) {
    console.log(button.getAttribute('value'));
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button> 
<button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
<button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
<button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
<button class="playBtn" value="{{filename}}"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**document.querySelector()** will return only the first found node. **document.querySelectorAll** would return a list that you would need to iterate.

However, this can be done with jQuery easily:

```
var selectedSong = '';

$('.playBtn').on('click', function()
{
    selectedSong = $(this).val();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m62yc1xu/).

Or with pure JS using **getElementsByClassName** or **querySelectorAll**

```
var selectedSong = '';

var a_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('playBtn');
// or querySelectorAll
// var a_btn = document.querySelectorAll('.playBtn'); 

for(var i = 0; i < a_btn.length; i++)
{
    a_btn[i].onclick = function() {
        selectedSong = this.value;  
    };
};
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp5swq0m/).

Answer (score 0):

#### Vanilla JS

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` so we need to iterate over that collection and apply the event listener to each element in it. By extending the NodeList prototype we can add our own little function to add any event to each node. We then have ourselves a nice jQueryesq method to use it:

```
NodeList.prototype.on = function(event,func) {
    [].forEach.call(this, function (el) {
        el.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    });
    return this;//return self to maintain chainability
};

//to listen for a click on each of these:
document.querySelectorAll('.playBtn').on('click',function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

You can even chain these events like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.playBtn').on('mouseover',function(){
    this.style.borderColor='red';
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    this.style.borderColor='';
});
```

Here's the [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnu6rkws/) and snippet:

```js
NodeList.prototype.on = function(event,func) {
    [].forEach.call(this, function (el) {
        el.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    });
    return this;//return self to maintain chainability
};

document.querySelectorAll('.playBtn').on('click',function(){
    alert(this.value);
    return false;
});

document.querySelectorAll('.playBtn').on('mouseover',function(){
    this.style.borderColor='red';
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    this.style.borderColor='';
});
```

```html
 <button class="playBtn" value="a">A</button> 
 <button class="playBtn" value="b">B</button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="c">C</button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="d">D</button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="e">E</button>
```

#### With jQuery

Of course if jQuery is available to you then all this is baked in. It doesn't directly answer your question of *"How do I get querySelector to get the value from the one I click on?"* because it's not directly using querySelector but it *does* do what you need:

```
$(function(){//wait for document ready
    $(".playBtn").on("click",function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcssLxdc/)

```js
$(function(){
    $(".playBtn").on("click",function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="playBtn" value="a">A</button> 
 <button class="playBtn" value="b">B</button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="c">C</button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="d">D</button>
 <button class="playBtn" value="e">E</button>
```